# Is it possible for an attacker to determine the original input to the S-Boxes in DES?

Tags: des

I am learning about DES, a Feistel 64-bit block cipher with 16 rounds. Is it possible that an intruder can determine the original input to the S-Boxes?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Are we talking about what kind of intruder?

Comment: The original input to what S-box? That of the first round? The last? All the rounds?